# Slide show effect in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to create on slide show in my iphone application which open if the user don't touch the screen for 30 second , for that i have made on method which reset the time when user touch the screen .

I have used nstimer class to handle timer event .

my problem is that even if invalidating the timer the event has been fire after the time interval my reset timer method is as per below

```
-(void) resetTimer {

    if(timerForScreenSaver != nil)
    {   
        timerForScreenSaver = nil;
        [timerForScreenSaver invalidate];
        NSLog(@"timer is invalidate %@ ",timerForScreenSaver);
    }

    timerForScreenSaver = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(showScreenSaver) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    NSLog(@"timer is set");
}
```

can any one help me to reset the timer .

Thanks and Regard
 
 
 Kunal Patel

Answer (score 2):

Swap the following two lines:

```
timerForScreenSaver = nil;
[timerForScreenSaver invalidate];
```

You make your timer nil so invalidating has no effect

Comment: i have already try this thing .. but it crash the application

Comment: may be you invalidate your timer more than once for some reason? With what error your application crashes?